# Find out if an object or model is a through model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a list of objects (all with a ManyToOne or ManytoMany relation to a user) which I'm trying to assign to a different user.
I'm using the Django Admin NestedObjects to collect all the objects related to the user. In my list with objects I have objects that are actually a `through` model instance. How can I determine while looping over the objects if the object I'm currently dealing with is an `through` model instance?

Example:

```
class SurveyQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('app.Question')
    survey = models.Foreignkey('app.Survey')
    order = models.IntegerField()


class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.Charfield()


class Survey(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield()
    questions = models.ManyToManyField('app.Question', through='app.SurveyQuestion')
```

If I encounter a SurveyQuestion instance in my list how do I know this is a through model instance? I've tried the `model._meta.auto_created` but this value is only True if you don't specify the `through` in the `ManyToManyField`

I'm looking for a generic solution, using only the object and it's (protected) attributes. Can it be done?

Comment: add a flag: `is_through=True` for the through model

Comment: I've considered this, but don't think it's the most sustainable solution. Whenever I create a a new through model I will need to remember to always add this property for my functionality to keep functioning properly. Other devs working on the project should also be aware of this. I'm looking for something more generic